# jQuery FadeIn spoiling css style datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, css, datepicker, fadein

I have a divider with id="DatePicker", and using the jQuery UI date picker widget, I apply the widget like so:

```
$("#DatePicker").datepicker();
```

When viewed in a browser, this shows up nicely.

HOWEVER

When I change the #DatePicker divider's display style to display:none; and apply a jQuery fadeIn("fast") function attached to some other event in the webpage (a button is clicked for instance), when the #DatePicker divider fades in, the CSS styling becomes obscured and the widget's Date Picker container doesn't stretch to fill content.

Good Style:

[image]

Bad Style (Happens after fadeIn()):

[image]

Comment: Try wrapping the entire datepicker in a `div` and fading that in instead.

Comment: the same problem occurs. it may be because the actual date picker is being generated dynamically inside the #DatePicker divider

Comment: Hmmm. Have you tried inspecting the DOM after the fadeIn to see what specifically is getting messed up?

Comment: The display is set from "none" to "block", but this doesn't effect it if the initial display property is set to "block" on page load.

Comment: I hardcoded the width+height of the container in css - which has caused some restrictions but looks better than above.